# How to generate a docker file for Flask-Angular app?

Tags: angular, docker, flask

I have an Angular application that I'm hosting on a Flask server using render_template(). I want to dockerize the project. When I looked online I could find tutorials for dockerizing pure Flask apps, or for dockerizing pure Angular apps. How do I dockerize my Flask-Angular apps.

Comment: How do you deploy them now? I'm guessing they aren't packaged as one anyway, since one runs on python and the other on Javascript.

Comment: Right now I haven't deployed it. I just wanted to know the steps to make this run since I'm new to Docker.

Comment: Your flask back-end and your Angular front-end should be in two seperate containers. Thus, what your finding online is perfectly valid. There's plenty of tutorials on Dockerizing Flask apps and Angular apps already. Put the two containers in the same network and they should be able to communicate with eachother.

Answer (score 0):

It depends in how you deploy it now. But the best approach is to have a docker compose file which instantiate your modules (flask and angular) as two separated service. You should not pack them as a one service.
But again, this approach depends a lot of your project structure.